# PHPMyAdmin foreign key not clickable because shortened with ellipsis

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, bug-reporting

I got long ukeys in my database and use `foreign keys` to connect the license with the main users table. By default they got a hyperlink and will ref me to the entry in the table, but because they get shortened by PHPMyAdmin also the query has the ellipsis.
Here is some explaination and proof:

**1. Failed Query:** (The query phpmyadmin does when I click the href)

```
SELECT * FROM `table`.`users` WHERE `ukey` = 'gKbybyf4jWUmEA0uKSrlfxsmERJC2piJNSmYTcrmEVmaJzHQ5S...'
```

**2. License Table** (Where I click on the foreign key)[image]

**3. href Query** (Page that opens up after I clicked it)[image]

**4. Value proof** (as you can see, the key exists not my fault)[image]

**5. href** (either contains ellepsis... so here we got a bug, right?)[image]

You know a fix for this? I cannot influence the version or configuration, because it is hosted.. but just for the case you want to know: PHPMyAdmin 4.7.7
Is there a fix anywhere? If not I would be proud if you can push the bug report.

*And sorry for weird german phpmyadmin text*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the image (demo) below, you can see that there is a clickable link which looks like `T` sign on top left corner of the table. That link toggles between `Partial texts mode` and `Full texts mode` in phpmyadmin. By default, it is set to `Partial texts mode`.

[image]

So, when you click on that link, the whole text reveals and the href link is also changed to the full text, I mean, the ellipsis is also removed from the href. So, it should work for you.

[image]

Comment: Well that was quite simple. :D never clicked what before..  Ok Thanks.. but they should still spend some attention on this bug

Comment: @FelixGaebler That might not be a bug too. May be developers have some other choices in that case. Who knows?

Comment: you are completly right, but I thought an Open Thread gets more attention.. You should definitly have your tick.
I will send a private request to the team

Comment: @FelixGaebler That's my pleasure. Thanks.

Comment: never bag for it again :D